# invalid cast from type 'void*' to type 'int*'

Tags: c

**Added2**: After change to `static` , it can correctly work in gcc 4.8.4 (ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14 .04.3) within **bash on ubuntu on windows**. **But** it can't work in windows10 using gcc 4.9.2(tdm-1). And i change the compiler to cygwin which has gcc 4.9.2,not the tdm-1 version. Weird, it works! So i think the complier also has some bug!

**Added1**: I'm very sorry i find my compiler is gcc not g++, i'm new to the program world,please forgive me. I used `.c` to build, but it has some memory-leak bug that i can't handle. So i change to `.cpp` to build, and these error come out. So this is my situation.

**windows 10 elipse gcc 4.8.4**. I use C language.

elipse give me an error: **invalid cast from type 'void*' to type 'int*' [-fpermissive]**.

elipse suggest these lines have the error

```
FullList = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
l = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
```

I don't know how to correct it. **Any lead would be appreciate!**

this is the function which involve this sentence.

```
#define ALLCHK(x) if (x == NULL) {printf ("allocation error\n"); assert(x);}
void Generate_Permutation(int N, int *p)
/* generate permutation of length N in p */
/* p is zero based, but the permutation is not */
{
  int i,j;         /* to loop */
  int lspot;         /* offset in l */
  int *FullList;       /* unpermuted */
  int *l;          /* left to be used */

  FullList = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
  ALLCHK(FullList)
  for (i=0; i<N; i++) *(FullList+i) = i+1;
  l = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
  ALLCHK(l)

  memcpy(l, FullList, sizeof(int)*N);
  for (i=0; i < N; i++) {
    lspot = (int)(URan(&seed) * (N - i));
    *(p+i) = *(l+lspot);
    for (j=lspot; j<N-i; j++) *(l+j) = *(l+j+1);
  }
  free(l); free(FullList);
}
```

Comment: The error is not from Eclipse (wich is an editor) but from the compiler. BTW are you coding in C or in C++, they are *different programming languages* ; and C++11 is very different from C++98

Comment: The rules are different for C and C++. Which one are you using?

Comment: You need to decide, as a first step, which language you are using, C or C++.

Comment: What is the definition of `ALLCHK`?

Comment: If coding in C, have you `#include <stdlib.h>` ? And if coding in C++, better use [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) ...

Comment: You should **edit your question** to improve it (tell which language you are using, which compiler, which version, which standard) Otherwise it will be closed as unclear

Comment: Looks like you're running a C program through a C++ compiler. C should look like that, C++ can't.

Comment: @Yu-FengQin You should include <cstdlib> if you want to use C library.

Comment: Thanks for all yours kind help! I will try what you tell me

Answer (score 5):

In C++, a `void*` is not implicitly convertible to a `int*`. You need to cast the result of malloc explicitly:

```
fullList = static_cast<int*>(malloc(N * sizeof(int)));
l = static_cast<int*>(malloc(N * sizeof(int)));
```

---

Since you are using C++, you would be better off with the `new` operator:

```
fullList = new int[N];
l = new int[N];

// some code...

delete[] fullList;
delete[] l;
```

While were at it, you can use a unique pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> fullList = new int[N];
std::unique_ptr<int[]> l = new int[N];

// no delete at the end of the scope
```

But even simpler, simply use a vector:

```
std::vector<int> fullList(N);
std::vector<int> l(N);
```

Comment: Why not just use `new` if they are using C++?

Answer (score 1):

To me, it seems like you are porting a C code snippet to C++ (for inclusion in a C++ project?).

**Consider this answer as a quick fix to your problem, not as the best solution.**

When using `malloc`/`free` in C++, you have to cast the `void*` pointer as returned by `malloc` to your desired pointer type:

```
FullList = static_cast<int*>(malloc(N * sizeof(int)));
l = static_cast<int*>(malloc(N * sizeof(int)));
```

The reason for this (when simply copying over C code) is that in C these casts are allowed to be performed *implicitly*.

Other options would be to compile that file with a C compiler, for which it might be enough to simply rename the file to an extension of `.c` instead of `.cpp`. Then, g++ (a C++ compiler) would automatically use gcc (the C compiler) to compile your code.

Again another option would be to rewrite this to "real" C++ code using `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`, but then you could equally well also rewrite it to use modern memory management (like std::vectors etc.).

Comment: You should not use `malloc`  in C++. You should use standard containers & smart pointers.

Comment: Why not just use `new`?

Comment: I agree. But this is some snippet of C code within a C++ project. I compare this case with using a C library in C++. There, I cannot simply say, hey library, use new instead of malloc, since you are running in a C++ program. And I guess, OP wants to apply minimal code changes to the ported code. So what is speaking against using malloc here?

Comment: Thanks for all yours kind help! I will try what you tell me.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you do not have to cast (void*) result of malloc. In C++, compiler cries, unless you cast.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help!